# How can I reduce the number of source blocks I use?

Tags: anylogic

I have a sample From To Table that shows how many agents are supposed to move from the conveyors (Left Column) to their stations (Tow Row) in 1 hour. I will be using this sheet as a database which my model can refer to.

Right now, I have 3 sources for each blue, red and lime conveyors with 3 separate events calling these sources to generate a constant number of agents according to the From To Table. Take the blueConveyor for example, 6 blue units will be generated (1 goes to blue Station. 3 goes to red Station and 2 goes to lime Station).

[image: sample From to Table]

If I were to scale my table up to 30x30, I would require 30 source blocks and 30 events which will get rather messy. Might there be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many things you have to do here to achieve your goal:

1) create a population of agents called conveyorAgents loaded from your database. Each agent will have parameters blue, red, lime and its name (blueConveyor for example)

2) each conveyorAgent will have a population of sources equal to the number of rate columns in your table (3 in this case for blue, red and lime) (I am assuming that your number of rows is always equal to your number of columns)
[image: source populaiton]

3) create a collection of events... the easiest way to do that is to create another population of agents in your conveyor agent.. each one will have an even that will control the source in question and will have the following action:

```
conveyorAgent.source.get(getIndex()).inject(1);
```

**CONCLUSION**
All this is just a guidance on how to do it... I am not putting all the details but it should be enough to get started with

Comment: Ok thank you @Felipe, im trying to digest. Does this mean the number of sources are reduced to just one? (The incoming conveyorAgents from this source will trigger the events)

Comment: yes... it is possible to have a population of sources... so even though you see one graphically, they can be as many as you want

Comment: Hi @Felipe, does the approach you suggest generate the conveyorAgents uniformly? Referring to the same from to table above, are 6 blue conveyorAgents, 6 red conveyorAgents and 13 lime conveyorAgents each being generated with a fixed rate over 1 hour?

Comment: @SamuelChua yes

Comment: I roughly understand the approach. What I have trouble visualizing is: When the conveyorAgents are created, will they stay in the system and use the events in the embedded population of agents to trigger the command: conveyorAgent.source.get(getIndex()).inject(1)?

Comment: have you tried? Why don't you model this and test your hypotheses and visualize yourself what happens under different circumstances?

Comment: Yes, I am stuck at the third step and am trying to scale down the table into a smaller one. Wouldnt the number of events be the same as the number of rows x columns in the table?